# Rails - escape_javascript without all the \n\n\n\n\n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using escape_javascript to return a partial to the browser via ajax.

Something like:

```
$("#inject").html("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial =>"feed/index")%>");
```

Problem is escape_javascript ends up outputing all kinds of wasted space like

```
\n\n\n\n\n                \n
```

Is there anyway in Rails to escape_javascript more efficiently? No need for \n or long gaps of spaces?

Thanks

Comment: Is the escape_javascript method creating the wasted space, or is it caused by your partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard Rails way to do this. You could just remove it yourself before passing it to `escape_javascript` like this:

```
$("#inject").html("<%= escape_javascript((render :partial => 'feed/index').squeeze(" ").gsub(/[\n\t]/,'')) %>");
```

I'm sure there's a sweet regular expression that would do it better, but this will get pretty close and won't harm your HTML. The gsub will replace newlines and tabs with nothing. The squeeze method will replace multiple occurrences of spaces with just one space. You don't want to remove all spaces because they likely occur intentionally in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks, that does work. though it would be great if there was a way to do this globally" or maybe I should make a helper like escape_javascript_squeezed. thoughts?

Comment: Ya, to do it globally, I think that would be a good idea to create a helper that did it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to revive this thread since I believe there is a misconception here.

The `escape_javascript` method, which can also be shortened to `j`, should not display any escaped line breaks (\n) when used with jQuery's `append`, `prepend`, `html` or functions of the like.

The most likely situation is that your rendered partial "feed/index" has another partial within it that is being escaped as well. This means you are javascript escaping your line breaks twice, which causes them to get interpreted improperly.